# Using Android's adb shell in OS X

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm trying to analyze my database from Androids adb shell in OS X terminal, but I don't know how to get it to work. I'm pretty sure I have to do some type of 'install' to be able to access it but a not sure how to go about this.

Comment: how to access adb via terminal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the official [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/adb.html):

> Examining sqlite3 Databases from a Remote Shell
>   From an adb remote shell, you can use the sqlite3 command-line program to manage SQLite databases created by Android applications. The sqlite3 tool includes many useful commands, such as .dump to print out the contents of a table and .schema to print the SQL CREATE statement for an existing table. The tool also gives you the ability to execute SQLite commands on the fly.
>
> To use sqlite3, enter a remote shell on the emulator instance, as described above, then invoke the tool using the sqlite3 command. Optionally, when invoking sqlite3 you can specify the full path to the database you want to explore. Emulator/device instances store SQLite3 databases in the folder /data/data//databases/.
>
> Here's an example:

```
$ adb -s emulator-5554 shell
# sqlite3 /data/data/com.example.google.rss.rssexample/databases/rssitems.db
SQLite version 3.3.12
Enter ".help" for instructions
.... enter commands, then quit...
sqlite> .exit
```

> Once you've invoked sqlite3, you can issue sqlite3 commands in the shell. To exit and return to the adb remote shell, use exit or CTRL+D.

Comment: ... you copied this from androids site. I've already read it, and the problem is getting adb to work

Comment: instead of being rude you'd better be more specific on what the problem is. "adb doesn't work" isn't specific at all. Does it recognize adb as a command you can execute from shell?

Comment: ok. typing what the documentation tells me to in terminal doesn't do anything. the command is not found. how do i get terminal to recognize it?

Comment: Follow the full instructions for installing the android SDK.  It sounds like either the 'adb' program hasn't been installed, or your path hasn't been set up to include the location where it resides.

Comment: I'm assuming it's because the path hasn't been setup. How do I go about doing that?

Comment: I had assumed your problem was finding how to get to the phone's SQLite from the shell, not getting your local shell to start ADB altogether; it was less than clear in the question. To make your shell find ADB, just set the PATH environment to include the tools directory from the installed Android SDK. See http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/2621/os_x_change_path_environment_variable/

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this: http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/2621/os_x_change_path_environment_variable/

Try changing your path to include the "tools" directory of your sdk.

Then type adb and see what happens.

Comment: No, I'm using OS X. What would the equivalent be?

Comment: Thanks! This is what I was trying to say, just didn't know how.